# Can I access to session values in onSessionEnded event in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

Can I access to session values from onStop / onSessionEnded functions?

```
onStop(function() {
            cat(file = stderr(), paste(app, session$clientData$url_protocol, sep = ' - '))
        })
```

That code gives me this error: *Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext: Operation not allowed without an active reactive context.*

There is a way to get session values inside this functions?

If not, there is a way to execute a function just before the session is ended?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll have to use `isolate` to access `reactiveValues` (such as `session`) in a non reactive context :

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  "Just close app after launch"
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  onStop(fun = function() {
    str(isolate(session$clientData$url_protocol))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I just realized that and you confirmed my theory ^^ , Thank you!